# Unix Sockets: select() with more than one set associated does more than it should do

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, unix, tcp

I have the following select call for tcp sockets:

```
ret = select(nfds + 1, &rfds, &rfds2, NULL, &tv);
```

rfds2 is used when I send to large data (non-blocking mode). And rfds is there to detect if we received something on the socket.

Now, when the send buffer is empty, I detect it with rfds2. But at the same time I get the socket back in rfds, although there is nothing that I received on that socket.

Is that the intended behaviour of the select-call? How can I distinguish orderly between the send and the recieve case?

Comment: Did you check which is signaled in FD_ISSET(rfds) or FD_ISSET(rfds2)?

Comment: Yes, I so that for rfds as well as for rfds2.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, when the send buffer is empty, I
>   detect it with rfds2

That's not correct. select() will detect when the send buffer *has room.* It is hardly ever correct to register a socket for OP_READ and OP_WRITE simultaneously. OP_WRITE is almost always ready, except in the brief intervals when the send buffer is *full.*

Comment: Ok. I meant that so, too. I register for OP_WRITE only when the send buffer is full and do'nt to it when the buffer has room again. So theoretically I should can use both variables!?

Comment: @dada under what circumstances is your application ready to both read from and write to a socket at the same time? Either you are waiting for a request or you are writing a response; or if you're the client you're writing a request or reading a rssponse. It's only obscure things like proxy servers that do both at the same time.

Comment: It's a event based application with an existing select()-call, and I need an event when the send buffer has room again to call send() on the next part of large data. And I need to register a event for read, too - leaving it out of consideration if this happens at that time in a real scenario. As far as I understand I's entirely possible to recieve some data while ours is sending.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. I have found the problem for myself:
The faulty code was after the select call (how I used `FD_ISSET()` to determine which action I can do).

I think my assumption is true, that there is only a socket in rfds, when there is really some data that can be received.

Comment: There will be a socket in the returned read set if the socket has been closed at the far end so your assumption is not 100% true.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm aware of that. Luckily thats also a case where recv does not block. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

If the socket is non-blocking that seems to be the expected behaviour. The manual page for select has this to say about the readfds argument:

> Those listed in readfds will be
>   watched to see if characters  become 
>   available for reading  (more 
>   precisely, to see if a read will not
>   block; in particular, a file
>   descriptor is also ready on
>   end-of-file)

Because the socket is non-blocking it is true that a read would not block and hence it is reasonable for that bit to be set.

It shouldn't cause a problem because if you try and read from the socket you will simply get nothing returned and the read won't block.

As a rule of thumb, whenever select returns you should process each socket that it indicates is ready, either reading and processing whatever data is available if it returns as ready-to-read, or writing more data if it returns as ready-to-write. You shouldn't assume that only one event will be signalled each time it returns.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. OP_READ indicates that there is something to read, either data or an EOS indication. The quotation you've given should read '*would* not block (i.e. if the socket were in blocking mode)', corresponding to EWOULDBLOCK. The Unix man pages don't share this problem.

Comment: That is exacty what is the problem: I detect that I can write, so I call a method that do a send(). And I also detect, that I can read, so I do a recv(), but this blocks, as there is nothing that can be recieved. I cannot set the recv()-call non-blocking because then I get always a EAGAIN.